# Android You Tube API within Tab Activity

Tags: android

Getting an error stating "an error occurred while initializing the YouTube player" when trying to launch activity consisting of youtube player/fragment inside a tab activity/ ActivityGroup. the same piece of code works in an independent app not having Tab/Activity Group on the same device. Same set of code is working in dummy app but not working in main app (with tabs). The app does have permissions, also have cleaned it and build it again but still facing the same issue. could some one please help?

Comment: it would be very helpful if you share some part of your codes for more clarification.

Comment: Have you checked the logs? It may happen because a Youtube video should be on a YouTubeBaseActivity and not on a fragment.

Comment: You can find a good workaround here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458919/integrating-youtube-to-fragment. You just need a newInstance method on your fragment for the adapter on the tabbed activity.