# implementing YouTube API v3 in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I'm trying to implement Youtube API in my android application which uses a viewpager to show videos and some relative information. I have implemented the same using webview but can't go through with the YouTube API. Can anyone help me solve the problem?
The major errors are:

- Null Pointer Exception: during pointing to YouTubeSupportFragment (app crash)
- View can't have overlapping views (app crash)
- If using FrameLayout instead of Fragment, video stops after 1 second of playback.
  I've seen dozens of YouTube Videos, tutorials, SO answers but still couldn't find any in the context of ViewPager implementation (except probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458919/integrating-youtube-to-fragment))

The MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
.
.
.
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.
youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {

            if (!wasRestored) {
                player.cueVideo(getResources().getString(R.string.vid1));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
}
}
```

The fragment in viewpager where video is to be shown:

```
public class VideoFragment extends Fragment implements
    YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{
.
.
.
//Returns fragment to be shown in the viewpager fragment
YTfrag f = YTfrag.newInstance();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, f).commit();
}

public static VideoFragment newInstance(String title, String desc, String link, String narrator, int narratorImage) {

    VideoFragment f = new VideoFragment();
    Bundle b = new Bundle();
    b.putString("title", title);
    b.putString("desc", desc);
    b.putString("link", link);
    b.putString("narrator", narrator);
    b.putInt("narratorImage", narratorImage);
    f.setArguments(b);

    return f;
}
```

YTfrag fragment:

```
public class YTfrag extends YouTubePlayerSupportFragment {

public YTfrag() {
}

public static YTfrag newInstance() {

    //Bundle b = new Bundle();
   // b.putString("video", video);
    //f.setArguments(b);
    //f.init();

    return new YTfrag();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerSupportFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_fragment);

    initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            try {
                    youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getResources().getString(R.string.vid1));
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Cant play video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("MainActivity", "onInitializationFailure");
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

The viewpager fragment layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:autofit="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewA"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.6"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <fragment
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/viewB"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".92">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:maxLines="3"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:textSize="19dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="@color/primary_text" />

                <me.grantland.widget.AutofitTextView
                    android:id="@+id/description"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="10dp"
                    android:minLines="1"
                    android:maxLines="9"
                    android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
                    android:textSize="17dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_weight=".08"
            android:baselineAligned="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/narratorImageIV"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:contentDescription="NarratorImagesImageView"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:text="Memed "
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="12dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/narratorNameTV"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Help of any sort will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find any solution?