# how to Integrate youtube to fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api

I am trying to implement you tube in fragment. before i were successful to implement you tube in an activity its working perfectly but at this time show black screen in fragment.Refrence i try ([Integrating youtube to fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458919/integrating-youtube-to-fragment))

Fragment code:-

```
    public class YoutubeFragment extends Fragment {

private MainActivity myContext;

private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;
private String mVideoId = "QdUoieQOZ2s";

private static final String YoutubeDeveloperKey = "AIzaSyBVKvfrmSBUaCsj850v2Ks-2FCWiXn_rEw";

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {

    if (activity instanceof MainActivity) {
        myContext = (MainActivity) activity;
    }

    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflate, container, false);

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey,
            new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                    if (!b) {
                        YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                        YPlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                        YPlayer.cueVideo(mVideoId);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

                }
            });
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fl_youtube, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
    return rootView;
}
```

}

Activity class:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

}
```

inflate Xml file:-

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fl_youtube"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"></FrameLayout>
```

Comment: use YouTube player instead of frame Layout or other layout.

Comment: i use it before using framelayout it cannot work for me.. can u upload a full code of youtube in fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment Code

```
private YouTubePlayer mYoutubePlayer;
private String mVideoId;

//Call this method after getting mVideoId
private void initializeYoutubeFragment() {

    YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(getString(R.string.youtube_key), new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
             if (!wasRestored) {
                mYoutubePlayer = player;
                mYoutubePlayer.setShowFullscreenButton(false);
                mYoutubePlayer.cueVideo(mVideoId);
             }

        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {


        }
    });
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.fl_youtube, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    initializeYoutubeFragment();
}
```

and XML

```
....<!--Put his frame layout wherever you need in fragment view xml-->
<FrameLayout
         android:id="@+id/fl_youtube"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:visibility="gone">
....
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: in my activity xml i put <Frame layout>  i want to know any one changes in activity class??

Comment: Yes the above code which you have posted will work perfectly fine for Activity but you cannot inflate a fragment inside another fragment using xml. You will have to use a FrameLayout to achieve that. Just add that <FrameLayout> to your fragment xml instead of YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Comment: it show again black screen..I Edit my code please check this code

Comment: See my edit and implement you Youtube fragment code on 'onViewCreated'