# YouTubePlayerSupportFragment in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, youtube, fragment

I have a `MenuActivity`, in the `MenuActivity` i have a SeguridadMenuFrament and in the `SeguridadMenuFrament` i have SeguridadFragment. 
In the `SeguridadFrament` i need implement `YoutubePlayer`.

In my `fragment_seguridad.xml`

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/TR_CARACTERISTICAS"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_14"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCaracteristicas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
        android:id="@+id/youtubePF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvCaracteristicas"/>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

In the SeguridadFragment.java

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_seguridad, container, false);

    mYoutubePlayerFragment = new YouTubePlayerSupportFragment();
    mYoutubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
                youTubePlayer.cueVideo("NMwE93GQcKs");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.youtubePF, mYoutubePlayerFragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    return rootView;
}
```

But when run the app and show the `fragment`, the app crash and show :

> 12-04 10:12:56.878 4342-4342/com.pixelcom.beta.pixelkartingsocios E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.pixelcom.beta.pixelkartingsocios, PID: 4342
>                                                                                               java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1373)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1482)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1450)
>                                                                                                   at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:636)
>                                                                                                   at com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r.e(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.a(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                   at com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.onCreateView(Unknown Source)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2354)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1419)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1740)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1809)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:799)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2580)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2367)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2322)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2229)
>                                                                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:700)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)*

Comment: have a look at my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/26459181/909317

Comment: I need implement a video in a Fragment, not in Activity. In your answer, you implement a fragment in activity but i have a fragment. @Sunny

Comment: It's in fragment not in activity.

Comment: You declare fragment in activity, but I declared a fragment in my SeguridadFragment (fragment). @Sunny

Comment: just declare a frame layout inside your fragment(SeguridadFragment) layout and use the code given in the link.

Comment: @Sunny I tried this but i get this error: 

`Process: com.pixelcom.beta.pixelkartingsocios, PID: 15267
                  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=com.google.android.youtube.api.service.START }
                      at android.app.ContextImpl.validateServiceIntent(ContextImpl.java:1209)`

What i can do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use in your layout a FrameLayout instead a Fragment

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/TR_CARACTERISTICAS"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvCaracteristicas"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_12"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_fragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And then in your Fragment class use this code:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(YoutubeDeveloperKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
                if (!b) {
                    YPlayer = youTubePlayer;
                    YPlayer.setFullscreen(false);
                    YPlayer.loadVideo("NMwE93GQcKs");
                    YPlayer.play();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider arg0, YouTubeInitializationResult arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: its working but video is getting stuck while playing.I couldn't sort out the problem :(

Comment: @anjujo sorry for the late response. Have you tried with different videos and check your connection? Do you still have the problem?

Comment: yes..I have opened another question in SO.Could you please check it?"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52361191/youtube-video-get-stuck-while-playing-in-fragment"