# Youtube video get stuck while playing in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, fragment

I am new to Android.I am trying to play youtube video while the fragment loads.That means video should be playing while open the app.When I use this in activity it works(YouTubePlayerView ),but when I use YouTubePlayerSupportFragment video get stuck and not playing properly.

this is the code for youtube:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
    FragmentTransaction transaction =getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();
    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize("AIzaSyA9Kka548d7RZYVBypAy4UWgvDvbUCP16c", new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
            if (!b) {
               YPlayer=youTubePlayer;

               // youTubePlayer.cueVideo("EjvfD61PXAw");
                YPlayer.loadVideo("EjvfD61PXAw");
                YPlayer.play();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        }
    });
```

in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_marginBottom="?android:attr/actionBarSize">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/youtubecontainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:visibility="visible" />

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/recently_viewd"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:text="Recently Viewed"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/_10sdp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Recently Added"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/viewallrecentlyadded"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="view all"
                android:textSize="@dimen/_10sdp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can anyone please help me??

this is the logcat

```
09-17 15:05:53.071 23505-23505/com.zinedroid.android.atmadarshantv D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage ACTION_DOWN
09-17 15:05:54.511 23505-23586/com.zinedroid.android.atmadarshantv V/RenderScript: 0x9f9c2000 Launching thread(s), CPUs 4
09-17 15:05:59.251 23505-23505/com.zinedroid.android.atmadarshantv W/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.widget.FrameLayout{1292f567 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}. The distances between the ancestor's edges and that of the YouTubePlayerView is: left: 0, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 (these should all be positive).
```

Comment: remove else block. you need to load video only once.

Comment: @Sunny I have removed it.But no change.Video is starting but it gets stuck :(

Comment: what is youTubePlayer? how are you initiating it?

Comment: please note the change i have done in code.i have initialised  private YouTubePlayer YPlayer;

Comment: sorry I can't guess what is the problem without any stacktrace or log. the code should be working. You can also post the activity code. are you attaching fragment properly to activity?

Comment: yes..I have included the logcat now

Comment: `YouTube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player. The YouTubePlayerView is not contained inside its ancestor android.widget.FrameLayout{1292f567 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-0,0}.` that is your issue. Some view is on top of youtube fragment. You can directly include youtubefragment in xml look at my answer where you commented.

Comment: i have included the  full xml.could you find any mistakes

Comment: scrollview and recylerview does not go well with each other. Try removing all code and just include `youtube_fragment ` in xml

Comment: unfortunately i have tried to put only framelayout in xml.but still same is happening in logcat

Comment: i have used  bottom navigation view in my app.is the issue emerges from that??

Comment: Can confirm, same issue here, and nothing to add to OP post...