# How to Handle YouTube Fragment OnSaveInstanceState

Tags: android, android-fragments, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

## Issue

The YouTube documentation does not clearly outline where to call `seekToMillis()` in the YouTube lifecycle of their API [guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/setup) or [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayer) for Android.

In order to make sure the YouTube player picks up from where it left of when the screen is rotated `seekToMillis(...)` is required. However, this method does not work as expected being called directly before or after `loadVideo(...)` or `play()`.

## Expected

Call `seekToMillis(...)` to start video at specific point in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

The `seekToMillis(...)` method works after events within the **YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener**. Therefore, the saved instance state bundle can be passed into the inner class made for the PlayerStateChangeListener.

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    binding = FragmentYoutubeDialogBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

    val youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance()

    youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(Auth.APP_API_ID, object : OnInitializedListener {

        override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: Provider, player: YouTubePlayer, wasRestored: Boolean) {
            if (!wasRestored) {
                youtubePlayer = player
                player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(MyPlayerStateChangeListener(savedInstanceState))
                player.setPlaybackEventListener(MyPlaybackEventListener())
                player.loadVideo(arguments!!.getString(ITEM_ID))
                player.play()
            }
        }

        override fun onInitializationFailure(provider: Provider, result: YouTubeInitializationResult) {
            // TODO: add log statement.
        }
    })
    childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtubePlayer, youTubePlayerFragment as Fragment).commit()

    return binding.root
}


private inner class MyPlayerStateChangeListener(var savedInstanceState: Bundle?) : YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener {
    internal var playerState = "UNINITIALIZED"

    override fun onLoading() {
        playerState = "LOADING"
    }

    override fun onLoaded(videoId: String) {
        playerState = String.format("LOADED %s", videoId)
    }

    override fun onAdStarted() {
        playerState = "AD_STARTED"
    }

    override fun onVideoStarted() {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            println("YT_CURRENT: " + savedInstanceState!!.getInt(YOUTUBE_CURRENT_TIME_KEY))
            youtubePlayer.seekToMillis(savedInstanceState!!.getInt(YOUTUBE_CURRENT_TIME_KEY))
            playerState = "VIDEO_STARTED"
        }
    }
```