# Cannot do FragmentTransaction with YoutubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-youtube-api

In my application I am using the [BottomNavigationViewEx](https://github.com/ittianyu/BottomNavigationViewEx) library to switch between fragments and in one of them I am using YoutubePlayerSupportFragment to display a youtube player. However it seems that it is not possible to fragment transaction because YoutubePlayerSupportFragment does not seem to be compatible.

Type mismatch.

Required: Fragment

Found: MidiaFragment

BottomNavigation in MainActivity:

```
viewEx.onNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        val fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        val fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.bnv_home -> {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, FeedFragmentBeta()).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.ic_destaques -> {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, DestaquesFragment()).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.ic_camera -> {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, ChatDeMidiaFragment()).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.ic_chat -> {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, ChatFragment()).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
            R.id.bnv_perfil -> {
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.viewPager, PerfilFragment()).commit()
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
            }
        }
        false
    }
```

Fragment:

```
class MidiaFragment : YouTubePlayerSupportFragment(), YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

private val GOOGLE_API_KEY = "ABC..."
lateinit var youtubePlayerView: YouTubePlayerView

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                          savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_midia, container, false)

    youtubePlayerView = view.findViewById(R.id.youtubePlayerView)
    youtubePlayerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY,this)


    return view

}

override fun onInitializationSuccess(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider, youTubePlayer: YouTubePlayer, wasRestored: Boolean) {

    // l2UDgpLz20M
    // 1-AozVirb88
    // PLOcMSsuppV4q38HhyXXRPxFpwbX_04jf3

    //youTubePlayer.cueVideo("l2UDgpLz20M")
    youTubePlayer.loadVideo("l2UDgpLz20M")

}

override fun onInitializationFailure(provider: YouTubePlayer.Provider, youTubeInitializationResult: YouTubeInitializationResult) {

}
```

Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBackgroundNightBlue"
    tools:context=".Fragment.MidiaFragment">

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubePlayerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Opening the fragment crashes the application.
How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this answer, there is already a Java implementation given, maybe it can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26459181/909317